# Android Open Contacts List in Same Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, contacts

In my android application .. I am using tab layout and I have three tabs .. and one tab needs to open the contacts page when clicked.. but the contacts page is opening outside the activity. But I need to open it inside the tab. I am giving my code.. if anyone knows how t do please help.

```
private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.contacts_activity);

           Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

           startActivityForResult(i, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Comment: Not possible. You want to embed component of another application into your app, that is not possible. Use you own contacts feature for that.

Answer (score 0):

`startActivityForResult(i, PICK_CONTACT);` will open up an activity from which you can select a contact. If you want it to be displayed inside a tab,
 You have to use [**Content Provders**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to get the contacts data and generate a similar UI yourself.

Refer these docs for more info:

1. [Contacts Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html)
2. [Accessing Contacts Data](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html)